# Constraining Bayesian multinomial logistic in R via JAGS

Tags: r, jags, stan, rjags

I am learning how to fit Bayesian multinomial logistic models in R. This is my first attempt at using JAGS via `rjags`. The code illustrates with a MWE what I am trying to do:

```
## simulate data
set.seed(123)

n=2000

rr<-rmultinom(n, 3, c(.1,.3,.2))

r2=as.numeric(rr==1)
r3=as.numeric(rr==2)
r4=as.numeric(rr==3)

abt=rbinom(n,1,.1);smk=rbinom(n,1,.3) 
age=rnorm(n);bmi=rnorm(n)

## load programs
library("rjags")

## model
NMMmodel.string <- "
  model{
      for (i in 1:N){ 

        ## outcome levels 2, 3, and 4
        r2[i] ~ dbern(pi2[i]) 
        r3[i] ~ dbern(pi3[i]) 
        r4[i] ~ dbern(pi4[i]) 

        ## linear predictors
        logit(pi2[i]) <- g[1]+g[2]*age[i]+g[3]*abt[i]+g[4]*smk[i]
        logit(pi3[i]) <- g[5]+g[6]*bmi[i]+g[7]*age[i]+g[8]*smk[i]
        logit(pi4[i]) <- g[9]+g[10]*age[i]+g[11]*smk[i]+g[12]*bmi[i]

        ## probability that outcome is level 1
        pi1[i]  <- 1-pi2[i]-pi3[i]-pi4[i]
      } 
      for (j in 1:12) {
        g[j] ~ dnorm(0, 0.01)
      }
    }
"
NMMmodel.spec<-textConnection(NMMmodel.string)

## fit model w JAGS
jags <- jags.model(NMMmodel.spec,
                   data = list('r2'=r2,'r3'=r3,'r4'=r4,
                               'abt'=abt,'smk'=smk,
                               'age'=age,'bmi'=bmi,'N'=n),
                   n.chains=4,
                   n.adapt=100)
```

Here are two questions, in order of **decreasing** importance:

**Question 1**: I would like to put a constraint on the estimated parameters indexed by `g[1]` to `g[12]` such that `pi1` lies between some arbitrary upper and lower bound: say, `a=0.25` and `b=0.75`. One way is to use rejection sampling, where rjags will reject all samples that return `pi1` less than `a` or greater `b`. How can I do this?

**Question 2**: What, exactly, is this program doing? For example, if this program implements a Gibbs sampler, is there a way to code it up without resorting to JAGS, or STAN, or BUGS? Something like the first set of code on [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/gibbs-sampler-in-c/) website?

Comment: Have you considered using multinominal neural networks instead from the `nnet` package? http://amunategui.github.io/multinomial-neuralnetworks-walkthrough/

Comment: Thanks @NickKnauer! No, I haven't for two reasons: 1) doesn't enable constrained bayesian, and 2) doesn't allow different covariates for each outcome level (very important for my application). If I'm wrong on either, pls let me know!

Comment: For (1), rejection sampling is very inefficient, especially when your constraint isn't consistent with the data.  You could code up the constraint in Stan so that it doesn't do rejection sampling, but you'd probably be better off with a simple Dirichlet prior (which you could do in JAGS).   For (2), yes JAGS does a generalized form of conditional sampling (Gibbs when you have conjugate priors and slice sampling in the general case).  You can go even higehr level with something like rstanarm and specify it like in glm() or lmer().  Of course, you could code it yourself.

Comment: Actually, you won't be able to use a Dirichlet prior directly.  Usually when you try to break the generative story of the data by putting priors on compound objects, things will go wrong.  Here, you are trying to control a complicated interaction of parameters.  It's usually much easier to control things by putting priors on the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the help @BobCarpenter. The actual problem is much more complex than this MWE. So despite it's inefficiency, I'd be willing to go with rejection sampling. Just don't know how to impose the constraints I need in JAGS.

Comment: You can use what they call the "zero trick" in BUGS---you'll need to figure out how to translate to JAGS.